# Why is that the gate current cannot be negative for SCR?

Tags: rectifier, scr

Why is that the gate current cannot be negative for SCR ? If the gate current is negative it should only increase the breakover voltage , why is that the SCR does not work ?

Comment: The SCR works just fine as does the PN junction (diode) that forms the gate -cathode connection.

Comment: But the PN junction will be reverse biased right ?

Comment: Look at the 2 transistor diagram about 1/3 way down the page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_controlled_rectifier

Comment: The gate is P type, the cathode N type so no, it is forward biased in operation and that's why the gate current cannot be negative

Comment: Look for GTO, Gate Turn-off Thyristor. There's an SCR that *can* take a negative gate current to turn off. However, their specifications are poor, they are easy to blow up and difficult to drive, and have been superceded by IGBTs and IGCTs.

Comment: because you cannot drive an NPN Vbe with a negative voltage

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "can't be negative". If the SCR is off you can reverse bias the gate, and a small amount of negative leakage current will tend to flow (depending on what anode bias voltage you have etc.).

For example, the [2N5064](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/2N5060-D.PDF) is rated to handle as much as -5V on the gate.

[image]

If the SCR is on, much more current will tend to flow (depending on the anode current), but this is not a well defined region of operation for most SCRs. Some will commutate (turn off) if you suck enough current out of the gate, but it's not guaranteed and I suspect it could damage the device under some circumstances.